# Why is the "out variable pattern" used so often in c++?

Tags: c++

*I don't know the actual name of the pattern*

I usually don't write c++ code but every time I am reading though it I see the same pattern over and over again.

I just found it again in Unreal Engine 4 which looks like this

```
FVector CameraLoc;
FRotator CameraRot;
GetActorEyesViewPoint(CameraLoc, CameraRot);
```

I always hated this pattern because I never knew which parameter gets changed and then sometimes  the function expected that the object is properly initialized.

Why is this pattern even used? Wouldn't it be much nicer just to wrap it in a struct?

```
struct ActorEyesViewPoint {
    FVector CameraLoc;
    FRotator CameraRot;
};
```

and

```
ActorEyesViewPoint GetActorEyesViewPoint();
```

Comment: it is often used in C with a return value of error code

Comment: You should note that C++ code in traditional game engines is rarely "modern" and often very conservative. It's not always good C++ examples. For example, it's very usual for game industry code to use double initialization (constructor + init function) while any modern C++ expert would immediately reject such pattern in code review (because it actually complexify the code maintenance and is totally avoidable).

Comment: "initialization (constructor + init function)" this is actually a good idiom IMHO. It allows you to delay the actual work of initializing the object, otherwise you permanentaly have to dynamically allocate objects to control when the work is done.

Comment: In my code, any argument passed by reference is always `T const&`. If I want to change the value, then I pass by pointer `T*`. It's then much clearer which parameters are possibly altered.

Comment: @AurélienVallée: There are even more effective techniques that not only delay the initializing of the object but its entire construction, and still prevent dynamic allocation. The techniques are similar to `boost::optional<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

This pattern is used to prevent the unnecessary copy of objects when returning from the functions. This is basically an explicit version of RVOs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Note that this is no longer necessary with C++11 move semantics

Comment: It's typically not necessary with (N)RVO, either.

Comment: Sure, but writing code triggering NRVOs is tricky and error prone. A simple change - i.e. adding a branch - could break the NRVO without anyone noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

An advantage of that pattern is that you can pass derived classes to functions taking base classes.

If you have

```
class A {  };
class B : public A {  };

void foo(A* a);
A bar();
```

and need an object of class `B`, `foo` is useful, but `bar` is not.